# How to efficiently write SQL statements to aggregate thousands of columns?

Tags: metaprogramming, dynamic-sql, dolphindb

Suppose I have a table with hundreds of columns,  I want to perform aggregation on each column with the same aggregate logic such as function `max`. In the following toy example, if I use statement as follows, it would be very cumbersome.  Is there a better way to write the SQL statement?

```
select max(000001), max(0000002)....from t group by date
```

---

```
>t=table( take(2015.01.05,5) as date, take(2015.01.05T09:30:00,5) as datetime, rand(10,5) as `000001, rand(10, 5) as `000002, rand(10,5) as `000003, rand(10,5) as `000004, rand(10,5) as `000005);
>t;
date       datetime            000001 000002 000003 000004 000005
---------- ------------------- ------ ------ ------ ------ ------
2015.01.05 2015.01.05T09:30:00 5      9      2      4      4
2015.01.05 2015.01.05T09:30:00 4      0      9      6      2
2015.01.05 2015.01.05T09:30:00 7      5      9      9      3
2015.01.05 2015.01.05T09:30:00 0      0      1      7      6
2015.01.05 2015.01.05T09:30:00 3      1      6      3      6
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use metaprogramming:

```
t=table(2015.01.05 as date,2015.01.05T09:30:00 as datetime,1.0 as `000001,2.0 as `000002,3.0 as `000003)
sql(select =sqlCol(t.colNames()[2:],max),from =t,groupBy=sqlCol(`date)).eval()
```

The output:

```
date    000001  000002  000003
2015.01.05  1   2   3
```